# Execute fortran code on startup?

Tags: initialization, fortran

Is it possible to have fortran execute code upon startup, without explicitly putting it into the main program?

### Usecase

Consider e.g. a routine that reads data from a configuration file with keyword-value pairs, which is used in different modules.

For the sake of code locality it would be favorable for valid keywords, as well as error handling for invalid values, to be defined in the module that needs the data.

Right now the only pattern to implement such behaviour, that I can think of, would be writing a setup subroutine in said module, which is called by the main program.

This means that changing the logic of a module may require a change of the main program. This seems harder to maintain than e.g. in Python doing something like

```
# ------ ./project/module.py ------
from project.config import register_keyword
register_keyword("some_setting")
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to python and interested in the mechanism of how the above function auto-initializes each module. Does it mean that the user passes a set of keywords to a module (from the main) and that module reads in those variables into a dictionary type from an external file automatically? Are those modules/routines also aware of the order of initialization somehow, or by calling register_keyword() in a correct order in the main?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use derived type constructors:

```
module foo

  implicit none

  ! only export the derived type, and not any of the
  ! helper procedures
  private
  public :: mytype

  type :: mytype
    ! internals of type
  end type

  ! Write an interface overloading 'mytype' allows us to
  ! overload the type constructor
  interface mytype
    procedure :: new_mytype
  end interface mytype

contains

  type(mytype) function new_mytype(setting)
    ! Some generic setting type
    type(setting_type), intent(in) :: setting

    ! do something with setting
    ...
  end function new_mytype

end module foo
```

---

```
program bar

  use foo

  implicit none

  type(mytype) :: thing
  type(setting_type) :: setting

  ! calls 'foo::new_mytype'
  ! all implementation details hidden away
  thing = mytype(setting)

end program bar
```

Comment: That's the way to do it !  Functions with side-effects, well hidden from anyone reading `main`.  Nothing bad could possibly happ....

Comment: Isn't that true of literally anything not inlined? In fact, `new_mytype` could be even marked `pure` to enforce no side-effects.

Comment: This still puts it explicitly into the main program though. The python example was intended to demonstrate that in other programming language it is possible to add new program configuration without *any* change of the to the main program. If cleanly separated, the module can add new behaviour to what I called `config` by being imported alone -- i.e. with no further line of code after the use statement. In C++ similar behaviour should be achievable with static constructors.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, this is not possible according to the [Fortran (2003) standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/04/04-007.pdf).

A "static" function call like your `register_keyword` would have to be done in the `specification-part` of a module definition. By general definition this `specification-part` could contain a `stmt-function-stmt`, but this is then explicitly forbidden in `C1105`: "... shall not contain `stmt-function-stmt`, [...]". So you are basically left with calling intrinsic functions only.

If you really do not want to edit your main program, but you are fine with an additional C++ intermediate file, then the following PoC works:

`prog.f03`:

```
program main

end program
```

`my_module.f03`:

```
module my_mod
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   contains
      function foo() bind(C, name="foo")
         integer(c_int) :: foo

         write (*,*) "hello, world!"
         foo = 10
      end function
end module
```

`my_module.cc`:

```
extern "C" int foo();
int a = foo();
```

Compile and link as follows:

```
g++ -Wall -c my_module.cc -o my_module.o
gfortran -Wall -o prog prog.f03 my_module.f03 my_module.o
```

There will be an output, despite the Fortran program being empty:

```
 hello, world!
```

I still would not recommend doing this, since it is likely not guaranteed that the Fortran RT environment is ready when the C/C++ global/static function call happens.

Comment: Why do you link Fortran 2003 in year 2017? Not that 2008 or 2015 change anything.

Comment: Because that's the standard I am using the most and it's the only one of the y2k+ standards which is supported (almost) completely by recent versions of all compilers, see for example https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2003Status

Comment: GCC supports features quite randomly, many features of F2008 were supported before many F2003 features.